# compare and output 2 different states

Tags: c#

I'm really new into c# and most time I fix my stuff with google but this time for such a simple task I'm hard stuck.

Basically I have an ID list which need to be compared from a website if the ids exist,
and my return should be

XYZ exist
XYZ does not exist.

I know the XYZ exist part is not included, its not even necessary I just want
the output in green if exist and red if doesn't exist.

Right now it straight jump to the ELSE state, except I put the ids hardcoded then it will actually do IF when the line exist...

here is my code:

```
string list = @"C:\\id.txt";
string site = "http://example.com/xyz.txt";
string output = client.DownloadString(site);

if (File.ReadAllLines(list).Contains(output))
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(list))
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    Console.Out.WriteLine("found");
}
else
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(list))
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.Out.WriteLine("not found");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?  First store the call to `File.ReadAllLines(list)` into a variable.  And if the contents of `id.txt` is too large to reason about, truncate it to just a couple lines.  Then run your program and inspect the  contents of your variable and see if it ought to match the call to `.Contains`.  Also, the idea that you are downloading content from a website and assuming that it will exactly match a single row in your input list seems dubious at best to me.

Comment: thanks, ive added a var looks better now and my id.txt is pretty small with only 5-10 lines of random numbers, i manage to get it to work but if it finds 1 id it will output everything that is in id.txt, and if nothing is present it will go to else state but aswell will print out everything in the txt file. so ive come a bit more far.. now i only need to print out ids that contain in the website and print out ids that doesnt contain in the website at the same time... i think it doesnt work with IF ELSE so trying to fix that and then its pretty much done